# database fetch value show in dropdown using laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

hello I am in big trouble please help me about database fetch value show in drop down using laravel 4 my code is below

```
   <?php //echo "<pre>"; print_r($user);exit; ?>
            {{ Form::select($user, $user ) }}
```

in print_r($user); showing all database value fetch from database but i want to show only value = id , user name field I try for each but not working any idea how to show value=id , user name filed

and result showing in to the drop down like this

```
 <select name="[{"id":"1","username":"skaka","name":"sandip","avatar_id":"1","gender":"1","dob":"1989-10-20","grade":"A","school":"kbpv","created_at":"2014-07-22 08:45:59","updated_at":"2014-07-22 08:48:04","parent_email":""},{"id":"2","username":"ttt","name":"test2","avatar_id":"2","gender":"2","dob":"1989-10-20","grade":"A","school":"kbpv1","created_at":"2014-07-22 08:58:25","updated_at":"2014-07-22 08:58:25","parent_email":""}]">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `{{Form::select()}}` the easiest way to achieve this is by calling your data from the database with `lists()` method.

So

```
$users = User::lists('username', 'id');
```

Now you have an array with data like this:

```
$users = [1 => 'skaka', 2 => 'ttt', ....];
```

So you are ready to use efficiently `Form::select()` by doing:

```
{{Form::select('dropdown_name', $users)}}
```

Comment: This is the common use so it has to work. Run a `var dump` the `$users` result form the db. What do you get?

Comment: Great please check the answer as a valid one if you like